# AWS Cli calls in bash script variable assignment when sending parent-id/child-id

Tags: shell, aws-cli, aws-organizations

My script needs to get OU parent for an account,
**Please note I do have a working bash script, with tilde quotes on aws cli commands only when being assigned to a variable, that is exactly same, but  for --parentid/--child-id parameters
shell check is not needed hence**

When I run corresponding aws cli on terminal, it works fine , I have

````
```
aws organizations list-parents --child-id <acctid input> --query Parents[*].Id --output text
```
````

However when I use same in bash as below it does not assign the value, process nulls out. bash script has

````
```

    for account in $(aws organizations list-accounts --query 'Accounts[].Id' --output text); do
       echo $account
       parent_ou=`aws organizations list-parents --child-id $account --query Parents[*].Id --output text`
    echo $parent_ou
```
````

The only addition from working script is the assignment of parent_ou

Note it does print account correctly, so its only the parent_ou assignment not working. Have a similar problem with another, that works on terminal but not within bash, note mocked parent_id

````
```
  b_ous = `aws organizations list-organization-units-for-parent --parent-id o_hhhhh_**** --query OrganizationalUnits[*].Id --output text`
```
````

The error is

````
```
 command "o_hhhhh_****" not found
```
````

I have tried using variable instead of hardcode value, its same error.

Any idea what maybe wrong with these variable assignments in bash?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know this aws command. Are you sure that it prints the parent_ou to stdout, and not to stderr?

Comment: yes exact same command runs successfully on terminal
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/list-organizational-units-for-parent.html

Comment: Well, the docs you are linking to, talk only about "Output", but not about stdout vs. stderr, but admittedly, it would be pretty bizarre design if they would write this information to stderr. So the `for`-loop works in your terminal? In this case, I would add a `set -x` and a `set -u` to your script; perhaps you can see from the trace, what's going on inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
for account in $(aws organizations list-accounts --query 'Accounts[].Id' --output text); do
  echo "$account"
  parent_ou=$(aws organizations list-parents --child-id "$account" --query Parents[*].Id --output text | tr -d '\n')
  echo "$parent_ou"
done
```

I had to put the cli command for parent_ou as above, in $();